# PREVIOUSMONTH returning selected months data rather than previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax

Using a measure, I am trying to return a previous months data. I have a month slicer and when selecting June for example, the measure is returning June's data not May's.

Here is the measure:

```
Prior months contact rate = 
CALCULATE(
    [Offline Contact Rate], 
    PREVIOUSMONTH('DIM - Date'[date_worked])
)
```

The offline contact rate measure simply finds the percentage of a number by dividing some filtered rows by the whole data set.

The offline contact rate uses data from the main table and the 'Dim - Date' table is a separate table which is marked as a date table. The two tables are linked using the 'date_worked' column which they both have.

Offline contact rate measure:

```
Offline Contact Rate =
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('main_table'), 
        FILTER(
            'main_table', 
            'main_table'[worktype]="Offline" 
                && 'main_table'[contact_reason]="Further information"
        )
    ),

    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('main_table'), 
        FILTER(
            'main_table', 
            'main_table'[worktype]="Offline"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you please post code for [Offline Contact Rate]?

Comment: Sure I will edit post

Comment: You should be able to see it there now

Comment: You have syntax issue in your provided code for  [Offline Contact Rate]. Is main_table and FACT - main_table are different table?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on the stack overflow post. I have edited this now. The problem is still the same

Comment: I have checked your both measure with my test data. Its working perfectly. Can you check one last thing that you have relation between your table "DIM - Date" and "main_table" using column "date_worked". That has to be a One to Many relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220558/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-bail-p).

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing parenthesis in your code. I have added them with some comments at the end of line.

```
Offline Contact Rate =
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('main_table'), 
        FILTER(
            'main_table', 
            'main_table'[worktype]="Offline" 
                && 'main_table'[contact_reason]="Further information"
        )
    ), //-- This closing parenthesis is missing 

    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('main_table'), 
        FILTER(
            'main_table', 
            'main_table'[worktype]="Offline"
        )
    ) //-- This closing parenthesis is missing 
) //-- This closing parenthesis is missing
```

Now, if it still not working as per expectation, just write your 2 FILTER part in the code as below-

```
FILTER(
    ALL('main_table'), //-- Just added the ALL function
    //-- other conditions as it is now
)
```

**If the issue is still there -Can you check one last thing that you have relation between your table "DIM - Date" and "main_table" using column "date_worked". That has to be a One to Many relation.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. The missing parenthesis was again a typo (sorry!). I have added 'ALL' but unfortunately the problem is still the same

Comment: Ok, deleting this answer. Talking to you in the comments section again :) please update the question with correct syntax.